# matching substring in 2nd array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

PHP newbie, I have two arrays, I need to loop through `array1` and where the `$value = 2`, see if there is a `$key` match anywhere in the `$key` of `array` (e.g. `uit` is found in `fruit1` and `fruit 4`) then divide the matching keys value by 2.

I've been trying to use `preg_match`, but something is going odd along the way and I'm not really sure where i'm going wrong. Any insights would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$array = array(
'fruit1' => 1,
'hugo' => 2,
'helmet' => 3,
'fruit4' => 4,
'captain' => 5);

$array1 = array(
'uit' => 2,
'tes' => 1,
'ain' => 3,
 );

 foreach($array1 as $key=>$value){
 if($value==2){
 $ch=$key;
 $pattern = '/[$ch]/';
 foreach($array as $key=>$value){
   if(preg_match($pattern, $key)){
     $newvalue =$value[$key]/2;
     echo "$key $newvalue";
   }}}}?>
```

Comment: So you just want to replace `fruit1` with `fr21`?

Comment: Can you please tell what is your expected outcome?

Comment: Its pretty unclear what you actually want it

Comment: I've tied to edit to make this more clear. Please let me know if it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 3):

### Assumption

So, basically, you want to check if each of the `$array1` keys is a substring of `$array`, is that right?

### First problem (the pattern)

The regex pattern `/[$ch]/` is probably incorrect since it means:

> **literally match a single character present in the following list ($, c, h)**

this pattern will match:

- **h**ugo
- **h**elmet
- **c**aptain

### Corrected pattern

I think you want something along the lines of `$pattern = '/' . $ch . '/';`.

In that case the var `$ch` gets expanded so for the first element of `$array1` it becomes `/uit/`.

This pattern means:

> literally match the sequence `uit`

This pattern will match:

- fr**uit**1
- fr**uit**4

### Preg_match is not needed

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
foreach($array1 as $needle => $val1){
    if($val1 == 2) {
        foreach ($array as $haystack => $val2) {
            if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
                echo "$haystack => $val2\n";
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

See code at [**PHP Sandbox**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49e3974bed8eafe19b7eda79de08c04d41423600)

Comment: thank you Tivie, this was the difficulty I was encountering (i.e. matching the sequence `uit`, by matching the substring, I can now change the value with `$newvalue = $value/2` to get my required value set.